# Oracle datatype: Should I use VARCHAR2 or CHAR

Tags: oracle, plsql

Should I use VARCHAR2 or CHAR as a datatype in Oracle?

It's been suggested to me to use CHAR for these new tables I need but I'm concerned since these new tables which will be used to populat existing tables that use a VARCHAR2 datatype.  I'm concerned about extra spaces being placed in the VARCHAR2 fields and with comparison issues.  I know there are ways to compare them using by trimming or converting them but I'm afraid it will make my code messy and buggy.

What are your opinions?

Comment: Err... extra spaces in VARCHAR2 fields? Or you mean OldTable/CHAR = NewTable/VARCHAR2 comparisons?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> I'm concerned about extra spaces being placed in the VARCHAR2 fields and with comparison issues. I know there are ways to compare them using by trimming or converting them but I'm afraid it will make my code messy and buggy.

It's actually quite the opposite. Using CHAR will force your strings to be a fixed length by padding them with spaces if they're too short. So when comparing CHARs to regular strings in whatever app is using the data, that app would need to add a trim every time. In other words, VARCHAR2 is the choice that naturally leads to cleaner code.

In general you should *always* use VARCHAR2, unless you have a very specific reason why you want a CHAR column.

If you're worried about strings that have extra spaces in the front or end, then there's a few options that come to mind:

- Make sure whatever process is doing the inserts does a trim on them before inserting.
- Add a check constraint on the column that ensures that string = trim(string).
- Add a before insert row-level trigger that does a trim on the strings as they get inserted.
- Make sure that you do a trim on the strings whenever you query the table

Answer (score 5):

Read:

- [CHAR versus VARCHAR2 Semantics (documentation)](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/A97630_01/appdev.920/a96624/b_char.htm)
- [Should I use char or varchar2 (AskTom)](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0%3a%3a%3a%3aP11_QUESTION_ID:123212348063)

Quote from AskTom article:

> The fact that a CHAR/NCHAR is really nothing more than a
>   VARCHAR2/NVARCHAR2 in disguise makes me of the opinion that there are
>   really only two character string types to ever consider, namely
>   VARCHAR2 and NVARCHAR2. I have never found a use for the CHAR type in
>   any application. Since a CHAR type always blank pads the resulting
>   string out to a fixed width, we discover rapidly that it consumes
>   maximum storage both in the table segment and any index segments. That
>   would be bad enough, but there is another important reason to avoid
>   CHAR/NCHAR types: they create confusion in applications that need to
>   retrieve this information (many cannot "find" their data after storing
>   it). The reason for this relates to the rules of character string
>   comparison and the strictness with which they are performed.

Comment: Please note that you should post the essential parts of the answer here, on this site, or your post risks being deleted [See the FAQ where it mentions answers that are 'barely more than a link'.](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#deletion) You may still include the link if you wish, but only as a 'reference'. The answer should stand on its own without needing the link.

Answer (score 3):

CHAR has interesting comparison semantics. If you only use VARCHAR2, then you do not need to learn the CHAR semantics. Honestly, I think if I had a field with a known fixed lenth, I would still define it as a VARCHAR2 and use a check constraint to enforce it's fixed lengthiness, instead of learning the CHAR comparison semantics.

Some will argue that CHARs are more efficient for fixed length data because the length does not need to be stored, but that is [untrue on Oracle](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0%3a%3a%3a%3aP11_QUESTION_ID:1542606219593#8216570788470).

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you stick to VARCHAR2.

You should use CHAR when the data is a known fixed length.

Answer (score 0):

Choose `VARCHAR2(size)` over `CHAR(size)`, since this is more space and time efficient:

Surprisingly or not, `CHAR(size)` allows assignment of strings with a length `len` shorter than `size`. In this case, ORACLE appends `size-len` spaces to the string for datatypes `CHAR` and `VARCHAR` and stores `size` characters.
The `VARCHAR2` datatype comes without padding, only `len` characters are stored.

```
CREATE TABLE Demo(col1 CHAR(4), col2 VARCHAR2(4));
INSERT INTO Demo (col1, col2) VALUES ('c', 'v');
```

As a result,

`col1='c   '` (padded with 3 trailing spaces, since the `size` of `col1` is `4` and the length of `'c'` is only 1). `col1='c'` evaluates FALSE, only `TRIM(col1)='c'` evaluates TRUE,

whereas

`col2='v'` evaluates TRUE without`TRIM()`, making the comparison more efficient.

Furthermore, comparisons between two `VARCHAR2` values fail fast if their lengths differ (independent of their `size`). In this case, no character-wise comparisons are required.
With `CHAR` and same `size`, the length check always fails due to padding. Thus, every character has to be compared until the first character mismatch or the end-of-string has been reached, whichever occurs first.

Since both `CHAR(size)` and `VARCHAR2(size)` don't prevent assignments of values shorter than `size`, define a length constraint if you need to assure that only values with a predefined length (which should equal `size`) can be assigned.