# Unable to create table oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle

I am unable to create this table in oracle and keep getting the error ORA-00942: table or view does not exist any help much appreciated!

```
CREATE TABLE Occupancy 
(
  PatientNo          CHAR(6),
  WardNo             CHAR(6),
  BedNo              NUMBER(2),
  StartOfOccupancy   DATE,
  EndOfOccupancy     DATE,
  CostsIncurred      NUMBER(6,2),
  PRIMARY KEY (Patientno,WardNo,BedNo,StartOfOccupancy),
  FOREIGN KEY (Patientno) REFERENCES Patient (PatientNo),
  FOREIGN KEY (WardNo,BedNo) REFERENCES Bed (WardNo,BedNo)
)
```

Comment: Do the tables `PATIENT` and `BED` exist?

Comment: Not related to your problem but if `PatientNo` and `WardNo` are numbers then you should really be storing them as such. Also, I would highly recommend using [`varchar2` instead of `char`.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7747184/oracle-datatype-should-i-use-varchar2-or-char

Comment: Do your user granted the Permission to CREATE table ?

Comment: @HiteshRiziya: a missing grant to create a table would cause a different error

Answer (score 1):

The tables `Patient` and `Bed` doesn't exist in the schema (or do not have a public synonym) where you are trying to create Table `Occupancy`. If they do exist in a different schema use `SCHEMA_NAME.Patient` and `SCHEMA_NAME.Bed` in the create statement, or create a public synonym for the two tables `Patient` and `Bed`. If you have privileges to reference those tables the new table should get created, otherwise the `REFERENCES` needs to be granted to your schema as

```
GRANT REFERENCES (PatientNo)
ON SCHEMA_NAME.Patient
TO YOUR_SCHEMA;
```

And

```
GRANT REFERENCES (WardNo,BedNo)
ON SCHEMA_NAME.Bed
TO YOUR_SCHEMA;
```