# Character string buffer too small error while calling Oracle function using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, oracle

plsql numeric value error while calling the oracle function from C# - please tell me how to remove that error.

> PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character string buffer too small

Code:

```
create or replace function testdotnet(h1 varchar2)
 return varchar2   
 as
x varchar2(250);
begin
      select 'hello' into x from dual;
      return x;
end;
```

C# code:

```
string CommandStr = "APPS.testdotnet";

using (OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection("User Id=apps;Password=***;Data Source=***"))
using (OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(CommandStr, conn))
{
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

    cmd.Parameters.Add("h1", OracleDbType.Varchar2).Value = "aaa";
    cmd.Parameters.Add("x", OracleDbType.Varchar2, 40000).Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;
    cmd.Parameters["x"].Size = 255;
    cmd.Parameters["h1"].Size = 255;

    conn.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    Response.Write( cmd.Parameters["x"].Value.ToString());
}
```

Comment: please try to you change `250` to `255` for `x varchar2(250);`, and look whether the error persists ...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character string buffer too small](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18731560/ora-06502-pl-sql-numeric-or-value-error-character-string-buffer-too-small)

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan still not working after changing 250 to 255

Comment: You are setting the size to 40000 when you add x as a parameter and afterwards you reset that size to 255. Why?

Comment: @bradbury9 nops i have already check it before posting this

Comment: @flexbuzzhour if you have edited the code in relation to the comments here, please edit the question so it reflects the current "not working" state of your code, not the code as it was before suggestions were made

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23199713/c-sharp-call-oracle-stored-function , modify your function to return a number and modify your code using that accepted answer as a model. If it works, then we know the problem is with the return varchar. If not, the problem is the input varchar (I suspect the return varchar also)

Comment: Why do you make `select ... into from dual;`? Simply write `return 'hello';` or `x := 'hello'; return x;`

Answer (score 3):

Maximum size of `VARCHAR2` is 32,767 bytes, 40,000 is not possible.

Change

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("x", OracleDbType.Varchar2, 40000).Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;
```

to

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("x", OracleDbType.Varchar2, 32767).Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;
```

or use `CLOB` if you need bigger data.

Answer (score 0):

My stored procedure had `"keys"` as an output parameter in definition.

```
command.Parameters.Add("keys", OracleDbType.Varchar2, 32767).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
```

That fixed it for me, passing the size of output varchar2 variable along with the type.

I hope this helps someone looking for the solution of this error.