# Oracle input parameter not able to get results

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have oracle stored procedure where I pass an input parameter and get a cursor as an output parameter:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE OS_DIVISIONDDL(
  p_dept_name       IN VARCHAR2,
  p_cursor_division OUT SYS_REFCURSOR
) IS
  tmpVar NUMBER;
BEGIN
  tmpVar := 0;

  OPEN p_cursor_division FOR
    select Division_code,
           Division_name 
      from DIVISION_TBL 
     where dept_code=p_dept_name;

EXCEPTION
 WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
   NULL;
 WHEN OTHERS THEN
   -- Consider logging the error and then re-raise
   RAISE;
END OS_DIVISIONDDL;
/
```

The input parameter I am able to see using dbms print, but where condition is not executed by server Am i going wrong anywhere

```
DIVISION_CODE   CHAR (10 Char)
DIVISION_NAME   VARCHAR2 (30 Char)
DEPT_CODE       CHAR (10 Char)
COMPANY_CODE    CHAR (3 Char)
LOCATION_CODE   CHAR (3 Char)
CREATED_DATE    TIMESTAMP(6)
CREATED_BY  VARCHAR2 (50 Char)
MODIFIED_DATE   TIMESTAMP(6)
MODIFIED_BY VARCHAR2 (50 Char)
```

Comment: could you, please, provide us with the result of "desc DIVISION_TBL"? or just list all the columns and their data types?

Comment: `dept_code=RPAD(p_dept_name,10);` CHAR always has all the allocated spaces filled. When you hard code the String the comparison will be right always.

Comment: I did hardcode the where condition i am able to get data when i Right click and execute with input param I am not able to get data

Comment: Never use `CHAR`. See e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/q/7747184/272735

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you have a problem of implicit convertions:

```
declare
  a             char(10) := '123';
  b             varchar2(100) := '123';

  dummy         integer;
begin
  select null
  into dummy
  from dual
  where a = b;
end;
```

this code raises "no data found" but looks totally the same.

The problem here is that char(10) is not equal "123" but equal to "123<7 spaces here>". And varchar2(100) remains "123".

Check for char and varchar2 differences e.g. [in Oracle docs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17952_01/refman-5.6-en/char.html)