# When to use Char over Varchar2

Tags: oracle, sqldatatypes

Is there any benefit of using CHAR over VARCHAR2 ? Specially Oracle database ? As I read around, there is none and actually many recommend using VARCHAR2

What is the difference anyway beside the fixed and varied length ?

Why if there is no benefits from it, is not removed from Oracle at all ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42165653/14955

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7747184/oracle-datatype-should-i-use-varchar2-or-char

Comment: Simply answer: **never**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Already asked and answered

[Oracle datatype: Should I use VARCHAR2 or CHAR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7747184/oracle-datatype-should-i-use-varchar2-or-char)

Just to avoid confusion about much wrong information. Here are some information about difference including performance

Reference: https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:2668391900346844476

> Since a char is nothing more than a VARCHAR2 that is blank padded out
>   to the maximum length - that is, the difference between the columns X
>   and Y below:
>
> create table t ( x varchar2(30), y char(30) );  insert into t (x,y)
>   values ( rpad('a',' ',30), 'a' );
>
> IS ABSOLUTELY NOTHING, and given that the difference between columns X
>   and Y below:
>
> insert into t (x,y) values ('a','a')
>
> is that X consumes 3 bytes (null indicator, leading byte length, 1
>   byte for 'a') and Y consumes 32 bytes (null indicator, leading byte
>   length, 30 bytes for 'a ' )
>
> Umm, varchar2 is going to be somewhat "at an advantage performance
>   wise". It helps us NOT AT ALL that char(30) is always 30 bytes - to
>   us, it is simply a varchar2 that is blank padded out to the maximum
>   length. It helps us in processing - ZERO, zilch, zippo.
>
> Anytime you see anyone say "it is up to 50% faster", and that is it -
>   no example, no science, no facts, no story to back it up - just laugh
>   out loud at them and keep on moving along.
>
> There are other "made up things" on that page as well, for example:
>
> > *"Searching is faster in CHAR as all the strings are stored at a*
> >     *specified position from the each other, the system doesnot have to*
> >     *search for the end of string.  Whereas in VARCHAR the system has to*
> >     *first find the end of string and then go for searching."*
>
> FALSE: a char is just a varchar2 blank padded - we do not store
>   strings "at a specified position from each other". We do search for
>   the end of the string - we use a leading byte length to figure things
>   out.